# How to create a right side menu in a page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, sitepages, menu

I want to put the company policy on the page as text, and I want to create a list of the contents of this policy such as introduction, table of contents, glossary, etc.

I want this list to be on the right of the page and when I click on the introduction as an example, the introduction text will appear to me on the left of the list, and when I scroll down the mouse, this list remains on the right to make it easier for the reader to move to the section he wants by simply clicking on it to show him the text on the left.

How can I create this list? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using SharePoint Online modern experience- your requirements can be broken down into

I - Create page anchor links. To do this

- Edit the SharePoint Page, then format the text you want to link to as Heading (Heading 1, Heading 2, or Heading 3)
- Republish the page
- Hover over the header, right-click with your mouse, then choose Copy Link from the pop-up window
- Create a link using the Quick Links web part, or a navigation link web-part

II - Make the right hand side links web-part sticky

- You will need to create a custom SPFx solution **OR**
- Add a Script Editor web-part on the page and use CSS to make an OOB web-part sticky - https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor **OR**
- Use a 3rd party web-part

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: First approach will not create a right side menu. Also, you have to manually add link to newly created heading/section each time you create a new heading/section.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to achieve using SharePoint out of the box functionalities.

However, there are few custom [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) solutions available to achieve your requirements.

Check below links for detailed information and code. You can use these solutions as it is or you can enhance them as per your requirements:

1. [Table of Contents Web Part](https://dmitryrogozhny.com/blog/table-of-contents-spfx-web-part)

   [image]
2. [Table Of Contents for SharePoint](https://gitlab.lsonline.fr/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/toc)

   [image]
3. [Page Navigator](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-page-navigator)

   [image]
4. [Page Sections Navigation](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-page-sections-navigation)

---

Using SharePoint out of the box approach:

You can use "Text" web part with headings (heading 1, heading 2, etc.) or sections headings which gives you direct hyperlink to heading/section.

Then you can use these hyperlinks in another text web part or quick links web part to create a table of contents on a page. To create links at right side of page, use [Vertical section](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-sections-and-columns-on-a-sharepoint-modern-page-fc491eb4-f733-4825-8fe2-e1ed80bd0899).

However, this will not create a fixed/sticky navigation and navigation will be hidden when you scroll down the longer page vertically.

**Reference**: [What is an Anchor Link in SharePoint Online?](https://www.orchestry.com/insight/tech/microsoft-sharepoint-online/sharepoint-online-anchor-links-how-what-why/)

Comment: thank you very much